# How to format all Java files in an Eclipse project at one time?

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting

I have an old Eclipse project and the code is not well formatted. I'd like to format all the `.java` files according to the settings in Eclipse. I don't want to edit every individual file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. Is there a way to format all my files? Perhaps an Eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 272, accepted):

Right click on the project root and select Source -> Format. This should work for at least version 3.8.1. and above.

If the above does not work, you're probably using an older Eclipse-version. In such case you can select your Source Folders by clicking on them while holding down CTRL, then select Source -> Format from the right-click -menu. Works with package-folders and class files also, in case you don't want to format the entire project.

Comment: Selecting project root worked fine for me to format all files in project, using Eclipse 3.8.1.

Comment: +1 selecting the project seems to work in eclipse 4.2 also.  Consider removing the strikethrough and editing the answer to include the alternate solution for those who encounter a problem selecting the project.

Comment: @Luke and Jason McVetta: Thanks for the info, I've edited the answer to mention that selecting project root works in newer Eclipses and made the second paragraph a bit clearer.

Comment: Actually, upon further testing I have determined that the difference is Package Explorer vs. Project Explorer.  In Project Explorer, it doesn't format all the files and in Package Explorer it does.

Comment: doesn't this has to auto format itself without having the option to use source->format??

Comment: This also formats other files in the the project like .xml, .css and .html. Is there a way to only format the .java files?

Comment: @Ikshvak autoformat is a thing, but when you change the formatting of your project, you need to reformat everything and this is not automatic

Comment: wooow thx a lot !! this is very helpful ... btw I'm using Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1) , It worked when I selected all the packages then right click, Source, Format

Comment: Now I worked with Mars Release (4.5.0) and it worked by selecting the classes, than Source - Format

Answer (score 16):

**I also had the Java Perspective ON and this was still not working.** My eclipse was only formatting css and Html files, but not JAVA ones.

Then, I located [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8898520/3617531) that explains this:

> **You must add Java Facet to the project to allow Java classes to be detected by Eclipse formatter**

Then, you should check on `PROJECT-PROPERTIES-PROJECT FACETS` and activate the Java facet for the project:

[image]

And by right-clicking on top of the `PACKAGE-EXPLORER` you will find the SOURCE - FORMAT option, and it will format Java files too.

> Be careful, check it´s package explorer, not Project Explorer (click
>   Window-Show View-PackageExplorer)

[image]

Answer (score 9):

This is the purpose of

> Source ->Clean Up...

selecting the appropriate options.

Answer (score 4):

In older versions of Eclipse (Indigo) it works from Package Explorer (not Navigator). Right click the package you wish to format then choose Source -> Format. It will format all classes in that package and its sub-packages.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse Mars.1 Release (4.5.1) version and above, just press 
<kbd>Right click</kbd> on the code typing area

> Src > Source > Format.

If you want to format individual `java` / `xml` file just do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>