# Run auto formatter on an entire C project in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, formatter

I am using Eclipse 4.6.3 and I want to run the auto formatter on an existing C project.

Apparently, this works for java:
[How to format all Java files in an Eclipse project at one time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133781/how-to-format-all-java-files-in-an-eclipse-project-at-one-time)

When I select single/multiple `*.c/*.h` source files explicitly and run "Source->Format", auto formatter works correctly. However, when I run "Source->Format" on the root directory, then only xml files in this directory are being auto formatted.

Are there any settings that allow me to run the autobuilder on every `*.c/*.h` file in my project?

Answer (score 1):

open the files using eclipse, select all using `ctrl + a`. Then hit `ctrl + shift + F` to format the file.

This works with java, maybe you can only modify the files manually in the method I stated above.