# How to format all JavaScript files in an Eclipse project at one time?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, code-formatting

I created a custom js-formatter in Eclipse and now I want to format all .js files.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5133781) answer for .java files, but I don't know how to do it for .js files.
When I tried "Source->Format" all my .xml files were formatted, but none of the .js files were.

I guess it depends on the type of Eclipse project, which files are formatted using "Source->Format"?
I'm looking for a way to do this without being dependent on the type of project.
I also checked if JavaScript is checked in "Files->Properties->Project Facets" but it already is.

My Eclipse IDE is called:
**Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.

Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)**